# How to find out if the whole Kernel was loaded into the RAM

Tags: kernel, arm, u-boot

I have a custom board with a NOR-flash, DDR3, eMMC and CPU.
Uboot is working fine and I can download/upload the linux kernel to the eMMC. When I run the application the Kernel gets booted only past the first stage. It gets stuck att second stage with error. ERROR: rootfs not found.

Is it possible to find out if the whole image gets uploaded to RAM when I run command RAMBOOT from Uboot? I am trying to figure out if the Impedance values are wrong. Or if it is something else.

It does looks like it gets uploaded correctly. see log below.

```
4107712 bytes read in 759 ms (5.2 MiB/s)
## Loading kernel from FIT Image at 740000000 ...
   Using 'custom_emmc' configuration
   Trying 'kernel' kernel subimage
     Description:  Linux kernel
     Type:         Kernel Image
     Compression:  gzip compressed
     Data Start:   0x7400000c4
     Data Size:    3825195 Bytes = 3.6 MiB
     Architecture: AArch64
     OS:           Linux
     Load Address: 0x700080000
     Entry Point:  0x700080000
   Verifying Hash Integrity ... OK
## Loading ramdisk from FIT Image at 740000000 ...
   Using 'custom_emmc' configuration
   Trying 'ramdisk' ramdisk subimage
     Description:  ramdisk
     Type:         RAMDisk Image
     Compression:  uncompressed
     Data Start:   0x7403a5f98
     Data Size:    233472 Bytes = 228 KiB
     Architecture: AArch64
     OS:           Linux
     Load Address: unavailable
     Entry Point:  unavailable
   Verifying Hash Integrity ... OK
## Loading fdt from FIT Image at 740000000 ...
   Using 'custom_emmc' configuration
   Trying 'fdt_custom_emmc' fdt subimage
     Description:  Flattened Device Tree blob
     Type:         Flat Device Tree
     Compression:  uncompressed
     Data Start:   0x7403e7ff4
     Data Size:    9897 Bytes = 9.7 KiB
     Architecture: AArch64
   Verifying Hash Integrity ... OK
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x7403e7ff4
   Uncompressing Kernel Image
   Loading Ramdisk to 703fc7000, end 704000000 ... OK
   Loading Device Tree to 0000000703fc1000, end 0000000703fc66a8 ... OK
   Reserved memory region for spin-table: addr=77ff04be8 size=18

Starting kernel ...
```

```
Starting kernel ...

00:00:00 Stage 1 booted. Starting stage2 boot @ 649 ms
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!! ERROR at line: 1065, errno: 2 error: No such file or directory
!!!! MSG: No rootfs_data partition could be found!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
00:00:00 Overall: 41 ms, ubifs = 1 ms
00:00:02 Starting application...
```

EDIT:
I got this result when I adjusted the Uboot:

Before:`mtdparts=spi0.0:1m(Uboot),256k(Env),256k(Env.bk),20m(Linux),20m(linux.bk)`

After:`mtdparts=spi0.0:1m(Uboot),256k(Env),256k(Env.bk),20m(Linux),20m(linux.bk),32m(rootfs_data)`

```
Starting kernel ...

[    3.975684] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[    4.510251] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 1 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[    5.044804] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 2 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[    5.579362] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 3 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[    6.113917] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 4 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[    6.648469] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 5 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[    7.183045] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 6 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[    7.717610] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 7 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[    7.727829] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 0, async page read
00:00:16 Timeout. Device /dev/mmcblk0p1 not found
00:00:16
00:00:16 Devices found:
    .
    ..
    mmcblk0boot0
    mmcblk0boot1
    mmcblk0
    ubi_ctrl
    i2c-155
    i2c-154
    i2c-153
    i2c-152
    i2c[   16.350287] reboot: Restarting system
```

Comment: The error message says that there is no root partition. This is unlikely to be caused by a partially loaded kernel; the latter would jump to a nonexisting instruction at some point. This is most likely caused by an incorrectly configured root disk. Perhaps line 1065 in whatever file provides more clues.

Comment: Added new info in the original post, se EDIT:

Comment: I don't know how U-Boot operates, but it obviously expects a device named `mmcblk0` with a partition named `p1`. You seem to have this device, but the partitions are named differently. I think you need to answer two questions: Who/what names the partitions on the SD-Card, and how is U-Boot configured to expect a partition `p1`. And consequently: How to modify the card's partition names so that U-Boot is satisfied, or how to configure U-Boot so that it works with the current names.

Comment: It was a hardware Error. Solved.